# Detecting specific Number Incoming Phone Call In Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app that notify me when a specific number calls me .
in short . the user must save a specific number and when this number call the app show a Toast or any thing.

what should i use in the broadcast Receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following code to get incoming call using `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                      //Here you will incomeing mobile number do your logic here
                Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

To get more reference [here](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/detecting-incoming-phone-calls-in-android)

Comment: can i add ainmation on native calling screen.

Comment: for example if someone is calling me the animation is start in calling screen ,i want to display hearts falling from up to dawn like water fall .

Comment: https://github.com/inez/CustomIncomingCallScreen refer this.

Comment: one more thing .when i open the app that you give me .there is no MainActivity in java file

Comment: @FahdMana download project try to run how its working check/.